# Delphi Access Violation on form show

Tags: forms, delphi, show, access-violation

Sorry for having to open new question but I can't find an answer anywhere.

My app is still in progress, but basically I'm trying to call another Form from my MainForm when initializing players, however I get an Access Violation error. Would you please explain to me why this could be happening?

My MainForm code:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons, ExtCtrls, jpeg, pngimage, getPlayer_u;...

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;

  InitGameSetup();
end;...

procedure TfrmMain.InitGameSetup();
begin
  SetWindowProperties();
  InitBackGround();
  InitMainMenu();
  InitGameBoard();
  InitScrabbleTileRack();
  InitPlayers();
//  GameLoop();
end; ...

procedure TfrmMain.InitPlayers();
var
  I : Integer;
  sName, sSurname : string;
begin
  setLength(Players, NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS);
  for I := 1 to High(Players) do
    begin
      GetPlayer(); ---------------- problem is here
      with Players[I] do
        begin
          Name := sName;
          Surname := sSurname;
        end;
    end;
end;...

procedure TfrmMain.GetPlayer();
begin
  frmGetPlayer.Show;
end;
```

My `frmGetPlayer`:

```
unit getPlayer_u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmGetPlayer = class(TForm)
    btnSubmit: TButton;
    edtName: TEdit;
    edtSurname: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSubmitClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    sPlayerName, sPlayerSurname : string;
  end;

var
  frmGetPlayer: TfrmGetPlayer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmGetPlayer.btnSubmitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sPlayerName := edtName.Text;
  sPlayerSurname := edtSurname.Text;

  if not ((Length(sPlayerName) >= 1) and (Length(sPlayerSurname) >= 1)) then
    MessageDlg('Please enter a name and surname.', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
  else
    Self.Free;
end;

procedure TfrmGetPlayer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Self do
    begin
      Position := poScreenCenter;
      BorderStyle := bsDialog;
    end;
end;

end.
```

My dpr:

```
program main_p;

uses
  Forms,
  main_u in 'main_u.pas' {frmMain},
  getPlayer_u in 'getPlayer_u.pas' {frmGetPlayer};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The error:

[image: Error message: access violation]

Comment: Where is `frmGetPlayer` assigned a value?

Comment: Use the debugger.

Comment: Had you actually implemented this code in the main form's `OnShow` event instead of its `OnCreaate` event, you wouldn't have this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you for responses untill thusfar. I realized that it was the oncreate event which was causing the problem, but why is that?

Answer (score 6):

Only your MainForm object is created automatically at program startup. Inside its `OnCreate` event, your Player Form object hasn't been created yet, so the `frmGetPlayer` variable is not pointing at a valid object.

`frmGetPlayer` is a global variable, so it is initially `nil`. The error message is telling you that you are accessing invalid memory near address 0, which is almost always an indication of accessing a member of a class via a `nil` pointer.

So, you can't call `frmGetPlayer.Show()` until after you have created the Player Form object and assigned `frmGetPlayer` to point at it.  Which the code you showed is not doing.